# Android: how to set bold text in navigation drawer (indicates the current activity)

Tags: android, adapter, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer. My problem is: I can't figure out how to set the text to bold. It's always the first item which is selected (in bold).

Ps: In my ListView, I added a header.

In my activity class:

```
// Setting the nav drawer list adapter
NavMainMenuAdapter adapter = new NavMainMenuAdapter(this,
                                                    R.layout.list_item_mainmenu,
                                                    items);
drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            View rowView = view;
            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textListItemMainMenuTitle);
            //tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            displayView(view, position, tv.getText());
            ((NavMainMenuAdapter)((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapterView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter()).selectItem(position);
        }
    });
```

My NavMainMenuAdapter class:

```
public class NavMainMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavMainMenuItem> {

private Context context;
private int mSelectedItem;

public NavMainMenuAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NavMainMenuItem> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

public void selectItem(int selectedItem){
    mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// ....

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_mainmenu, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the data item for this position
    NavMainMenuItem item = getItem(position);

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageListItemMainMenuPicture);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textListItemMainMenuTitle);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textListItemMainMenuCounter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(item.getIcon());
    txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(item.getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(item.getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    txtTitle.setTypeface(null, position == mSelectedItem ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried instead of passing null as the first parameter, pass textView.getTypeFace()?

Comment: Make sure the new selected item is correct in the `selectItem()` method. `Log.d("mSelectedItem", "mSelectedItem: " + mSelectedItem);`

Comment: Yes the value is correct in the selectItem() method. But, I don't know why, in getView() method the value changes (the first call, the value is ok, and another call is done after that - why? - and selectItem is equal at 0). So it's not the same object Adapter instance... why?

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter' `getView()` method

```
txtTitle.setTypeface(null, position == mSelectedItem ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);
```

replace the above line by

```
txtTitle.setTypeface(txtTitle.getTypeface (), position == mSelectedItem ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys I understand why I have this behavior: when I select an item in my drawer menu, I start a new Activity. Each Activity extends a base Activity which contains menu drawer management. So I have 4 activities, so I have 4 menu drawer (and so 4 adapters); and my variable mSelectedItem is updated in the current Activity. The next to show, will not have mSelected variable updated (stay at 0). That's why it's always the first item in my menu which is in bold mode.